# SQL Selecting from same table with different criteria performance issue

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    s.Site AS SiteName, 
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(sc.Count), 0) 
     FROM xmedius_api.faxcapday sc 
     WHERE sc.Date_Time BETWEEN '2017-08-28 04:00:00' AND '2017-09-27 18:42:05' 
       AND sc.Type = 'FaxSentGood' AND sc.Site = s.Site) AS SentCount, 
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(sfc.Count), 0) 
     FROM xmedius_api.faxcapday sfc 
     WHERE sfc.Date_Time BETWEEN '2017-08-28 04:00:00' AND '2017-09-27 18:42:05' 
       AND sfc.Type = 'FaxSentFail' AND sfc.Site = s.Site) AS SentFailedCount, 
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rfc.Count), 0) 
     FROM xmedius_api.faxcapday rfc 
     WHERE rfc.Date_Time BETWEEN '2017-08-28 04:00:00' AND '2017-09-27 18:42:05' 
       AND rfc.Type = 'FaxReceivedFail' AND rfc.Site = s.Site) AS RecdFailedCount, 
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rc.Count), 0) 
     FROM xmedius_api.faxcapday rc 
     WHERE rc.Date_Time BETWEEN '2017-08-28 04:00:00' AND '2017-09-27 18:42:05' 
       AND rc.Type = 'FaxReceivedGood' AND rc.Site = s.Site) AS RecdCount 
FROM 
    xmedius_api.faxcapday s 
WHERE 
    s.Date_Time BETWEEN '2017-08-28 04:00:00' AND '2017-09-27 18:42:05' 
    AND s.Site = 'system'
GROUP BY 
    s.Site 
ORDER BY 
    SentCount DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

The above query works great but I am trying to multi-purpose for other searches. I need to be able to remove the following to get values for ALL sites (not just a specific case)

When I remove the following, the query basically craps out on itself:

```
AND s.Site = 'system'
```

I have tried many combinations of this query but non work. What is the best trick to get this working?

Comment: We have no idea what your data structure looks like, or what *"the query basically craps out on itself"* means. Additionally, unless you're using both `mysql` and `sql-server`, you shouldn't tag both - nor do I see any `php` in the question. Please [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46456515/edit) to remove the unrelated tags and provide some additional information.

Comment: Chances are `s.Site` is not indexed!

Comment: @cmorrissey that was it... was reading about indexes but looks like the downside now is updating/inserting that table? it contains around 50,000 records at any given time however it is only updated once a day.

Comment: Yes there is a cost for updating indexes. No it's not usually an issue.